# Does this sequence of functions converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Given the sequence of functions

$f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$x\mapsto\begin{cases}2nx, & x\in[0,\frac{1}{2n}] \\ -2nx+2, & x\in (\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}) \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

---

The functions look like this:

[image]

---

Does this sequence converge pointwise or uniformly against a function $f(x)$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

My thoughts:
It doesn't, since for $n\rightarrow\infty$ the first interval becomes $[0,0]$ and the second $(0,0)$. Since $[0,0]$ is just $0$ and $(0,0)$ is a nonexistent interval, we have two cases for $x$: $x=0$, in which case the function is $2nx$, and $x\neq 0$, in which case the function is $0$.

Now here is the part I don't quite understand:

For $n\rightarrow\infty$, if $x=0$ the function would be $2\cdot\infty\cdot 0$. How do I interpret that?

Anyway, since the slope of the first function section gets higher and higher with each iteration, it must be vertically for $n\rightarrow\infty$, right?

Am I correct with my thougts? And what about uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function converges pointwise to the zero function. It is trivial that $f_n(0) = 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $\alpha \in (0,1]$, by archimedianity there is some $n$ for wich $\alpha$ lies in the interval $[\frac{1}{n},1]$ and therefore for that $n$ and every larger integer, $f_n(\alpha) = 0$. This means exactly that $f_n \to 0$.

Comment: But why is $f_\infty (0) = 0$? How do you calculate $2\cdot\infty\cdot$ 0?

Comment: The definition of $f_n \to g$ is that for every point $p$ in the domain of the sequence ${f_n}$, the limit of the real sequence $f_n(p)$ converges to $g(p)$.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but the limit of $f_n(0)$ as $n$ approaches infinity would be $2\cdot\infty\cdot 0$ which is undeterminate form. When we analyze a normal sequence for convergence and we get something like $\frac{0}{\infty}$ we don't just write: the limit is $0$ because it gets multiplied by $0$. Instead we use l'Hospital's rule. So why is it right to say the limit is $0$ in this case just because something gets multiplied by $0$?

Comment: Not really, because x *is* zero, it's not approaching zero.

Comment: Note that, for every $n$, $f_n(0) = 0$ so $f_n(0)$ is the zero sequence, and therefore its limit is zero.

Comment: So a term like $xy$ is only undeterminate if for example $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $y\rightarrow 0$? When we do $y=0$ instead, the term becomes $0$, even while $x$ still does approach infinity?

Comment: Y es, exactly, the indeterminacy arises only if one term approaches zero and the other infinity. If one of the terms *is* zero, the sequence converges to zero.

Comment: Last question: Is my argumentation in the original post correct? That is, if $n\rightarrow\infty$ then the middle case disappears and we have $2nx=0$ for $x=0$ and the third case is $0$ by definition? Therefore $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: I think your intuition is ok but not very formal. To prove what you ask requires a bit more machinery. Others have included more detailed proofs, but basically you eventualy need to use archimedianity.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $f_n(0) = 0$ for any $n$.

Now, let $x_0\in(0,1]$ be fixed and let $N:=\lfloor\frac{1}{x_0}\rfloor+1$, then $f_n(x_0) = 0$ for any $n>N$. Since, by the Archimedean property of the real numbers, such an $N$ can always be found, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ and your sequence converges to the function $f(x)=0$ pointwise.

However,$\underset{x\in[0,1]}{\sup}|f_n(x)| = 1$ for any value of $n$, therefore $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\underset{x\in[0,1]}{\sup}|f_n(x)| = 1$ and thus the convergence is not uniform.